# cannot run bundle using zshell, get git errors

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh, bundle

I have oh-my-zshell installed and these are my plugins

`plugins=(git rails ruby coffee npm bundler)`

I can run npm fine, but whenever I run bundle install inside m project i get this error

```
etching git@github.com:company/feature.git
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Retrying git fetch --force --quiet --tags "/Users/username/.bundler/cache/git/feature-f4806bda91cc5c0ec60094eaaf874acb2cc908a0" due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags "/Users/username/.bundler/cache/git/feature-f4806bda91cc5c0ec60094eaaf874acb2cc908a0"` in directory /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/feature-c27c388ea2d0 has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/username/.bundler/cache/git/feature-f4806bda91cc5c0ec60094eaaf874acb2cc908a0'
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Retrying git fetch --force --quiet --tags "/Users/username/.bundler/cache/git/feature-f4806bda91cc5c0ec60094eaaf874acb2cc908a0" due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags "/Users/username/.bundler/cache/git/feature-f4806bda91cc5c0ec60094eaaf874acb2cc908a0"` in directory /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/feature-c27c388ea2d0 has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/username/.bundler/cache/git/feature-f4806bda91cc5c0ec60094eaaf874acb2cc908a0'
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags
"/Users/username/.bundler/cache/git/feature-f4806bda91cc5c0ec60094eaaf874acb2cc908a0"` in directory
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/feature-c27c388ea2d0 has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
'/Users/username/.bundler/cache/git/feature-f4806bda91cc5c0ec60094eaaf874acb2cc908a0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: **Looks like if using the bundler plugin you need to use bi or bundle_install instead of bundle install see comments below.**

Well, judging by the errors I'd say you don't have permissions to read or write on the git folder.

Try:

```
# chmod -R o+rw .git
```

At the root of your project.

Comment: i get this from ls -al drwxr-xrwx  15 user.name  CENTRO\Domain Users    510 Oct  9 13:33 .git

Comment: Could it be that you are within the group CENTRO\Domain Users and you aren't user.name? You are only missing writing permissions for group. If so you could either regain ownership or assign write permissions to the group. You should try removing the specified folder as well.

Comment: i switched back to bash and this started to work, seems like its only an issue on zsh, is there a similar encounter?

Comment: when i do whoami i get my username though

Comment: I'm looking at the bundler.plugin.zsh and I'm seeing an alias of bundle_install but not bundle install. Try using that instead of bundle install, or bi (the alias).

Comment: that solved it!!! gosh, does zshell forbid you to use non-aliased commands...

Comment: Maybe bundle_install is ZSH specific, glad it works.

Comment: If I get it correct, the solution is to use `bundle_install` and not the `chmod` command given in your answer. For future visitors you should edit your answer accordingly. (Especially as it is the accepted one!)

Comment: yep, on a side note, bundle install works again today on zsh, i've probably done a whole lot of stuff so i didn't catch the exact solution, but thumb this up if you can fix it with, setting up ruby gem and then  gem install bundler.